# Is there a powershell ConfigurationName equivalent in pywinrm?

Tags: powershell, winrm

As part of a project I am working on, I need to remotely run PowerShell commands from a linux client.
Since I am using a linux client I can't use the straight forward PowerShell solution (New-PSSession, Invoke-Command, etc.).
I have decided to use pywinrm to run the PowerShell script remotely and it seems to be working fine when I am using an administrator account.

But I need to restrict the privileges of the account for security reasons.
When I am connecting from a powershell client I can easily do it using ConfigurationName option.
For example:
`New-PSSession -ComputerName ServerName -ConfigurationName CONFIG_NAME`

But I couldn't find the equivalent of the ConfigurationName parameters in pywinrm.
Does this option exists in pywinrm?

I tried to run powershell comamnds remotely from a linux client, when using a non admin account.

I expect to be able to create a powershell connection from a linux client using pywinrm while restricting the allowed commands (ConfigurationNanme)

Comment: I am confused. `pywinrm` is a Python client for the Windows Remote Management service. Do you want to run Python remotely? You may add a `Python` tag then. 